# Cant crawl scrapy with depth more than 1

Tags: scrapy

I couldn't configure scrapy to run with depth > 1, I have tried the 3 following options, noone of them worked and the request_depth_max at summary log is always 1:

1) Adding:

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
settings.overrides['DEPTH_LIMIT'] = 2
```

to spider file (the example on site, just with different site)

2) Running the command line with `-s` option:

```
/usr/bin/scrapy crawl -s DEPTH_LIMIT=2 mininova.org
```

3) Adding to `settings.py` and `scrapy.cfg`:

```
DEPTH_LIMIT=2
```

How should it be configured to more than 1?

Answer (score 4):

warwaruk is right, The default value of DEPTH_LIMIT setting is 0 - i.e. "no limit is imposed".

So let's scrape miniova and see what happens. Starting at the `today` page we see that there are two tor links:

```
stav@maia:~$ scrapy shell http://www.mininova.org/today
2012-08-15 12:27:57-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.15.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
>>> from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
>>> SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['/tor/\d+']).extract_links(response)
[Link(url='http://www.mininova.org/tor/13204738', text=u'[APSKAFT-018] Apskaft presents: Musique Concrte', fragment='', nofollow=False), Link(url='http://www.mininova.org/tor/13204737', text=u'e4g020-graphite412', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
```

Let's scrape the first link, where we see there are no new tor links on that page, just the link to iteself, which does not get recrawled by default (scrapy.http.Request(url[, ... dont_filter=False, ...])):

```
>>> fetch('http://www.mininova.org/tor/13204738')
2012-08-15 12:30:11-0500 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mininova.org/tor/13204738> (referer: None)
>>> SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['/tor/\d+']).extract_links(response)
[Link(url='http://www.mininova.org/tor/13204738', text=u'General information', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
```

No luck there, we are still at depth 1.  Let's try the other link:

```
>>> fetch('http://www.mininova.org/tor/13204737')
2012-08-15 12:31:20-0500 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mininova.org/tor/13204737> (referer: None)
[Link(url='http://www.mininova.org/tor/13204737', text=u'General information', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
```

Nope, this page only contains one link as well, a link to itself, which also gets filtered.  So there are actually no links to scrape, so Scrapy closes the spider (at depth==1).

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, it helped to set `follow=True` when defining [`Rule`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules):

> `follow` is a boolean which specifies if links should be followed from
>   each response extracted with this rule. If `callback` is `None` `follow`
>   defaults to `True`, otherwise it default to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

The default value of [`DEPTH_LIMIT`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-limit) setting is `0` - i.e. "no limit is imposed".

You wrote:

> `request_depth_max` at summary log is always `1`

What you see in the logs is the statistics, not the settings. When it says that `request_depth_max` as `1` it means that from the first callback no other requests have been yielded.

You have to show your spider code to understand what is going on.

But create another question for it.

UPDATE:

Ah, i see you are running mininova spider for the [scrapy intro](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html/#write-a-spider-to-extract-the-data):

```
class MininovaSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'mininova.org'
    allowed_domains = ['mininova.org']
    start_urls = ['http://www.mininova.org/today']
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['/tor/\d+']), 'parse_torrent')]

    def parse_torrent(self, response):
        x = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        torrent = TorrentItem()
        torrent['url'] = response.url
        torrent['name'] = x.select("//h1/text()").extract()
        torrent['description'] = x.select("//div[@id='description']").extract()
        torrent['size'] = x.select("//div[@id='info-left']/p[2]/text()[2]").extract()
        return torrent
```

As you see from the code, the spider never issues any request for other pages, it scrapes all the data right from the top level pages. That's why the maximum depth is 1.

If you make you own spider which will be following links to other pages, the maximum depth will be greater then 1.

Comment: @ warwaruk: "the spider never issues any request for other pages", but MininovaSpider extends CrawlSpider which uses `rules` on every page to recursively scrape more pages, so there is often no need to issue Requests manually.

Comment: I haven't worked with `CrawlSpider`, and i don't know if it goes recursively. But in that specific example i quoted, the spider doesn't do in depth requests.

Comment: By default it will recurse as deep as it can into each page, scraping all the links it finds with `rules`.  The reason that it stops at depth 1 is that there are actually no links to scrape from the `today` page (except for the link to itself, which does not get re-requested with the default behaviour).

Comment: >The reason that it stops at depth 1 is that there are actually no links to scrape from the today page< So you know why `request_depth_max` is equal to `1`?

Comment: yes, i know why... because there are no links.  see my answer.

Comment: @stav, sorry, i thought you are the original poster. By saying "the spider never issues any request for other pages", i meant that for no other links are followed, i.e. it's just a site issue